# Suggested method for creating figure from spectrogram?

Tags: spectrogram-annotation, spectrogram

How do folks suggest creating a publication ready spectrogram? I'm looking to show just ~5secs and 1000Hz. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which program/tools are you using? Matlab, R, Python, Scilab, others?

Comment: The spectrogram settings depends on what you would like to illustrate. Please give some context.

Comment: Same question but focused on R: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/preferred-r-code-settings-packages-for-publication-level-spectrograms

Comment: Can you upload some audio that you would like to visualize? And note which particular characteristics you would like to show or emphasize?

Answer (score 5):

My approach to generate useful (publication ready) spectrograms considers

- aspect ratio to fit expected ratio in paper
- font size of axes readable when scaled down to (e.g. single column in two column publication)
- appropriate axes labels with sufficient font size
- information to be shown should have at least 1 pixel on low res computer screen (75 dpi information resolution)
- publisher may expect 600dpi figure but keep features larger
- colour scale such that relevant information is visible in printed version (especially BW)

In summary, if you print your spectrogram in the final size as BW picture and you see relevant information discussed in the paper and can read numbers and text, it should be good for the reader of your publication.

Answer (score 4):

My personal choice: I often generate the spectrograms directly from my analysis program (e.g. the data as preprocessed by a Python script) - but if not, then I use [Sonic Visualiser](https://www.sonicvisualiser.org/) which is designed for good visuals, and since it is intended as a visualiser the options are all right there to tweak manually and to export as PNG etc.