# Spectrograms with ggplot2?

Tags: r, spectrogram

My question is related to [this one](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/preferred-r-code-settings-packages-for-publication-level-spectrograms)
I'm looking for a way of plotting beautiful spectrograms that would be compatible with ggplot2 in R, so that I can add some lines, points, annotations, or control font size etc.
Does someone know what package could do that / if this exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The seewave package allows you to create spectrograms in R, and includes the ggspectro function which allows you to use ggplot to plot spectrograms. You can find examples here https://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/

Answer (score 6):

I have used the `seewave` package with `ggplot` very successfully.  I needed to tweak the values a bit depending on the file you are using.  Here is an example code.  you will need to point it to your own wav file.

````
# Make a spectrogram in R
# 
# This script makes a spectrogram for a single sound file
# 
# Author: Abram F.
# Date Created: 11 Sep 2019
# Date Last Updated 11 Sep 2019

library(tuneR)
library(seewave)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sound_path<- "C:/Users/cc/Downloads/MANO7_20220928_MANO7_20220919_043500_0_startsec_38_label_possBAOW (1).wav"
save_path<-"test.png"



# Load sound (only loading first 10 seconds)
s<-tuneR::readWave(sound_path,from =1,to = 3.5,units = "seconds")

# load the spectrogram
sound_data <- seewave::ggspectro(s,
                                 norm = T, 
                                 flim=c(0.1,10), # frequency limits, kHz 
                                 wl = 512, # fft window length (start w/ 1024 or 512 )
                                 ovlp = 80) # % window overlap, x direction


# get the spectrogram data to darken the background and make nice contrast
hmm<-seewave::spectro(s,plot=F) 

# get the high and low contrast numbers to cut out 
top =quantile(hmm$amp,probs = .99)
bottom = quantile(hmm$amp,probs = 0.4)

# reset all values above the top value to the top and below the bottom value
sound_data$data$amplitude_cut <- dplyr::case_when(sound_data$data$amplitude>top ~top ,
                                                  sound_data$data$amplitude<bottom ~bottom,
                                                  TRUE ~ sound_data$data$amplitude)



# print the plot

sound_data+
  geom_raster(aes(fill = amplitude_cut)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'plasma',
                       na.value = plasma(n = 100)[1])+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(0,10,1),minor_breaks = seq(0,10,.25))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,10,1),minor_breaks = seq(0,10,.25))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

ggsave(gsub(".wav",".png",sound_path),height = 3,width = 6,units = "in",dpi = 150)

```
````